# Cloned a MBR partition on a new HDD with GPT, not showing up in Win10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I'm having a problem with a new HDD. My old HDD was making annoying noises so I replaced it with a new one. I cloned the old MBR partitioned disk with MiniTool Partition Wizard and set GPT as the new partition type.

I booted into Windows and the new drive didn't show up in Explorer. I opened disk management tool and found that the drive was listed there, unlabeled. All options in the context menu were greyed out and the drive displayed 100% free space.

I then opened Partition Wizard and the drive was displayed there properly, with proper driver letter, size, free space, label and partition type. I've checked my BIOS settings multiple times to ensure that I'm booting in UEFI mode and I even tried toggling some other switched like CMS without results.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? I couldn't find an identical situation anywhere on the internet. I know I could just convert it to MBR but I'd like to fix the problem now since I'm gonna face it sooner or later when I want to get a 3TB hard drive and have to use GPT partitioning.

[image: All options greyed out]

[image: Looks good in MiniTool]

EDIT:
Even in the Partition Wizard the disk management options are greyed out so I can't convert to MBR even if I wanted to.

[image: Convert to MBR greyed out]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points that aren't directly related to your problem, but that could create problems in the future:

- If you were booting OK and it was disabled, enabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in your firmware will do *nothing* helpful. The CSM enables you to boot BIOS-based OSes on new EFI-based computers. This can be a useful feature, but it's 100% irrelevant once an EFI-mode OS has booted. Worse, if it's active, your computer might decide to boot media you insert in BIOS mode. This could complicate future OS installations, since the installer might boot in BIOS mode, see the existing EFI-mode installation, and either fail or create a configuration that will be difficult to manage.
- Since Windows Vista (SP1, IIRC), Windows has been able to handle either MBR or GPT data disks. It doesn't matter whether the main OS has booted in BIOS mode or in EFI mode; the data disk can take either form. Thus, you shouldn't be too concerned with that -- except of course for the fact that your disk is being mis-detected....

Now, to your problem: It appears that Windows and Partition Wizard are interpreting your disk's data structures differently. This could indicate bad data structures written to the disk by Partition Wizard, which you used to prepare it. It's hard to be more precise without seeing detailed output from a program that provides more low-level information, such as my own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`).](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) If you care to try it, please launch `gdisk` on the disk, then type `p`, `v`, `x`, `o`, and `q`. These commands will show critical information and then exit. For instance:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 90D4AB8D-9A26-4E95-AAFA-18560E508493
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7814037134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      7814037134   3.6 TiB     8E00  Linux LVM

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 2014 free sectors (1007.0 KiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 2014 (1007.0 KiB) in size.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): o

Disk size is 7814037168 sectors (3.6 TiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   4294967295   primary     0xEE

Expert command (? for help): q
```

Absent that detailed information, my first guess is that you've accidentally done one of two things:

- **Created a GPT with an illegal protective MBR** -- Part of the GPT data structure is a *protective MBR,* which is designed to make GPT-unaware tools think the disk is fully partitioned. It could be that the disk has GPT data structures, but the protective MBR is malformed in some way that's causing the Windows tools to tell you that the disk is not partitioned in the way Partition Wizard says it is. That tool, by contrast, would be doing less stringent tests on the protective MBR and showing you the GPT data structures. The `gdisk` commands I've suggested you run will test the validity of the data structures and show both GPT and MBR data structures. Although it's conceivable that Windows would object to something that `gdisk` wouldn't bother reporting, I don't know of any specific problems that would fall through this particular crack, so it seems unlikely.
- **Created a hybrid MBR** -- This is a special case of the preceding one, really. A [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) is a variant on a legal GPT disk that can be interpreted as an MBR disk by GPT-unaware OSes, because the protective MBR contains data that it normally doesn't contain. (The GPT spec, in fact, is quite clear about what should be in a protective MBR, and a hybrid MBR violates that spec.) Windows favors the MBR side rather than the GPT side when shown such a disk, whereas macOS and Linux both treat such disks as GPT disks. This OS difference makes hybrid MBRs useful when dual-booting older versions of Windows on Macs, since Windows 7 and earlier don't boot well in EFI mode, but OS X installs in EFI mode. Thus, with a hybrid MBR, Windows can boot in BIOS mode and think the disk is an MBR disk, but OS X can boot in EFI mode and see the disk as a GPT disk. If you've accidentally created a hybrid MBR, though, it's conceivable that Partition Wizard is telling you about the GPT side whereas the Windows partitioning tool is telling you about the MBR side. (The commands I've suggested you run in `gdisk` will report both GPT and MBR data structures, if both are present, thus testing this hypothesis.)

If either of the preceding hypotheses is correct, then the problem can be fixed by creating a fresh protective MBR. Several tools can do this. (Perhaps Partition Wizard can; but if so, I don't know how to do it with that tool.) In `gdisk`, you'd launch the tool on the disk, type `x` to enter the experts' menu, type `n` to create a new protective MBR, and type `w` to save the change (you'll also have to confirm this change). I do not advise doing this without first diagnosing the problem; however, if your original disk is still working OK, taking the chance of trashing the disk if I'm wrong might not be too bad.

If you can't or don't want to use `gdisk` (or some other tool that provides similar details) to diagnose the problem, then my advice is to redo the disk preparation and copy operations using some other tool. My knowledge of Windows disk-cloning tools is limited, so I don't have any specific suggestion (unless perhaps you were dual-booting with Linux, in which case I'm familiar enough with `ntfsclone` to assist you with that). Broadly speaking, though, I'd say you should prepare the new disk, be sure that Windows can read it, and then do a file- or filesystem-level clone of the original disk to the new one. I have a sneaking suspicion that your problem was caused by the all-in-one-step method you used, perhaps combined with the fact that you were cloning from MBR to GPT.

Answer (score 0):

Is your old MBR a system drive? Since your boot from the second drive (disk 1 in Disk Management), it doesn't matter if you convert to MBR from GPT. Your system drive (disk 1) is GPT, you have to use UEFI boot mode.
I am not familiar with Partition Wizard, so do not know if it supports clone MBR to GPT. I suggest you try to [clone MBR to GPT disk](http://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-mbr-to-gpt-disk-4348.html) again with another freeware.